# How to properly return T from a generic method while implementing an interface?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I am working through a bug. In recreating the bug for the following sample I was able to determine why the problem is happening. But I am stuck for a better solution. So given the following program:

```
public interface IFoo<T> {
    T OutputType(T param);
}

class Foo : IFoo<Foo> {
    public virtual Foo OutputType(Foo param) {
        Console.WriteLine("foo");
        return param;
    }
}

class Bar : Foo, IFoo<Bar> {
    public virtual Bar OutputType(Bar param) {
        Console.WriteLine("bar");
        return param;    
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        CallOutputType(bar);
        bar.OutputType(bar);
    }

    static void CallOutputType<T>(T t) where T : Foo {
        t.OutputType(t);
    }      
}
```

I was expecting the output to be:

```
bar
bar
```

But what I am getting is:

```
foo
bar
```

Seeing the problem simplified like this it is obvious that **Bar.OutputType** isn't overriding **Foo.OutputType**. What are my best options for improving this design? 
**Bar.OutputType** can't override **Foo.OutputType** because the signatures are different. Changing the signature of **Bar.OutputType** to match **Foo.OutputType** won't work because then **Bar** won't be implimenting **IFoo**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uh, I'm not too familiar with this stuff but shouldn't it be:

```
static void CallOutputType<T>(T t) where T : IFoo<T>
{
   t.OutputType(t);
}
```

It worked when I compiled it.

Comment: Hmm, I am trying to test this now, what I think I might end up doing is in CallOutputType - ((IFoo<T>)t).OutputType(t); I can't change the method constant for other reasons.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction, using the interface to call the method works.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding this to the Bar class:

```
    public override Foo OutputType(Foo param)
    {
        return this.OutputType((Bar)param);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about converting your interface definition such that `param`'s type is declared to extend `IFoo`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd second Spencer on that - when you generic constraint is T : Foo, it typecasts your Bar into a Foo, and obviously you get to call the OutputType method of the Foo class then.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain what it is you are wanting to accomplish in the end but would this help?

If you add a Generic to what ever implements IFoo then you can specify the type when the derived object is created...

```
public class Foo<TFoo> : IFoo<TFoo>
{

}

//Then you code would allow this...
//Again other then returning Bar both times I am not certain exactly what you are 
//wanting to accomplish But specifying the type at create will allow you to return Bar 
//even if you created a Foo or a Bar...

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo<Bar>();
        CallOutputType(foo);
        foo.OutputType(foo);
    }

    static void CallOutputType<T>(T t) where T : Foo {
        t.OutputType(t);
    }      
}
```